# How do i get the value on the table and save it into the variable

Tags: python, sqlite

```
import sqlite3
from hashlib import sha256


conn = sqlite3.connect('pass_manager.db')
connect = input("Es tu primera vez en la app?\n")
conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS KEYAD
            (PASS_KEY TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL);''')
if connect == "si":
    contraseña = input("Ingresa tu contraseña\n")
    ADMIN_PASSWORD = contraseña
    conn.execute('''INSERT INTO KEYAD(PASS_KEY) VALUES (?)''', (contraseña,))

else:
    conn.execute('''SELECT PASS_KEY FROM KEYAD''')
    contraseña = conn.fetchone()
`I want to get the value from the table and save into the variable to check if the login its ok`
    ADMIN_PASSWORD = contraseña


connect = input("Cual es tu contraseña?\n")

while connect != ADMIN_PASSWORD:
    connect = input("Cual es tu contraseña?\n")
    if connect == "q":
        break
```

I get this error

File "j:/Proyectos y Trabajos/Python/PythonProjects-master/PasswordManager/password_manager.py", line 17, in 
    contraseña = conn.fetchone()
AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Connection' object has no attribute 'fetchone'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call fetchone on a cursor, not a connection

```
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('''SELECT PASS_KEY FROM KEYAD''')
    contraseña = cur.fetchone()
```